# combing a query into a single row

Tags: sql, t-sql

A SQL query I am running is returning duplicate rows, similar to the below:

```
id    | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
31443 | 1       | NULL    | NULL
31443 | NULL    | 3       | NULL
31443 | NULL    | NULL    | 5
```

What I want my query output to return is:

```
id    | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
31443 | 1       |       3 | 5
```

This is how my query currently works:

```
SELECT 
    id.[identifier] as 'id',
    (SELECT c.[value_1] WHERE c.[value_type_id] = '3') as 'value_1',
    (SELECT c.[value_2] WHERE c.[value_type_id] = '4') as 'value_2',
    (SELECT c.[value_3] WHERE c.[value_type_id] = '5') as 'value_3'
FROM Client as c
INNER JOIN Identity as id ON id.[id] = c.identity
```

Comment: This are not duplicates in your example at the beginning?

Comment: @VBoka I mean duplicate rows, the first example shows repeats of a single ID. I want to group them together into 1 row.

Comment: Aside: Is `c.[value_type_id]` really a string, not an integer? You keep comparing it to strings, i.e. `'4'` rather than `4`.

Answer (score 2):

It *seems* like what you are actually after here is a `PIVOT`/Cross tab:

```
SELECT 
    id.[identifier] AS id,
    MAX(CASE c.[value_type_id] WHEN 3 THEN c.[value_1] END) AS value_1,
    MAX(CASE c.[value_type_id] WHEN 4 THEN c.[value_2] END) AS value_2,
    MAX(CASE c.[value_type_id] WHEN 5 THEN c.[value_3] END) AS value_3,
FROM dbo.Client AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.[Identity] AS id ON id.[id] = c.[identity] --IDENTITY is a reserved keyword, I suggest using a different name here
GROUP BY id.[identifier];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Value_1,2,3 may not always be a number. what is the purpose of MAX?

Comment: To get the `MAX` (maximum) value, @TomDickson ... Literally it does "what it says on the tin." I have no idea what you mean by `Value_1` may not be a number. if your sample isn't representative of your data, then there's we can't be expect to cater for it.

Comment: @TomDickson . . . So what?  `max()` works on almost all data types.  It is not limited to numbers.

Comment: I think the only data type `MAX` doesn't work on is `bit`. Perhaps `sql_variant`, but that's a completely different kettle of fish...

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select id.id,
(select c.value_1 from Client  v1 where c.value_1 is not null and 
v1.identity=c.identity) as value_1,
(select c.value_2 from Client v2 where c.value_2 is not null and 
v2.identity=c.identity)as value_2,
(select c.value_3 from Client  v3 where c.value_3 is not null and 
v3.identity=c.identity) as value_3
FROM Client as c
INNER JOIN Identity as id ON id.id = c.identity;
```